# IIS: Add Feature

Tags: iis, installation, ip, restrictions, ip-restrictions

I need to edit IP rules using the IP Address and Domain Restrictions feature in IIS 7.0, but on my Windows 7 machine this feature is not present in my IIS. Does anybody know how to go about adding this feature to IIS? I can't find a download anywhere...or a section in IIS to add features. Thanks :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be a restriction of IIS on the client.  Closest I could find was the [Dynamic IP Module](http://www.iis.net/download/DynamicIPRestrictions). I don't [see that module on the web anywhere either](http://www.iis.net/download/All).

HOWEVER:

You probably just don't have the feature enabled:

1. Open the Control Panel
2. Search for Programs and Features
3. Select Turn Windows Features on or off
4. Expand the IIS node
5. Check out the security section, I think it falls under IP Security, either way it doesn't hurt to turn it all on, especially for a dev. environment.

[image: screenshot of IP and Domain Restrictions feature selected under Security node]