# IIS - Windows Server 2012 - IP Address and Domain Restrictions

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, ip-restrictions

I'm having a hard time trying to find where it is located the IIS Security features in Windows Server 2012.

The common steps :

```
1.Open the Control Panel
2.Search for Programs and Features
3.Select Turn Windows Features on or off
4.Expand the IIS node
5.World Wide Web Services > Security and enable IP Security.
```

However, these steps are not valid for Windows server 2012.

**Where is it located Security/IP Address and Domain Restrictions feature ?**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Then why this question is valid? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899669/iis-add-feature

Comment: @RowlandShaw I don't know, might be better on [sf]. Or might still be on-topic here on SO. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, I got it, the steps are:

```
1. Open the Control Panel
2. Search for Programs and Features
3. Select Turn Windows Features on or off
4. A wizard is displayed. Click Next until you get to "Server Roles" option at left side.
5. Select and expand Web Server (IIS) .
6. Select and expand Web Server.
7. Select and expand Security.
8. Check IP and Domain Restrictions.
```

I hope it helps.[image]